# How to get the list of files in a directory

Tags: bash, files, array

I try to create an array/list which stores file names inside a folder. The below command creates for unknown reasons a `:`. How is possible to remove `:`?

```
> a=$(ls split*)
> echo $a
split_sam.o4433568 split_sam.o4433616 split_sam.o4441795 split-data-1:
```

Comment: What operating system and terminal are you running? I've tried your snippet both in Fedora (bash) and Alpine (ash) and it works properly. Isn't it actually a part of the file name?

Comment: If that is the case, you could replace the colon by using `echo ${a/:/}` to output the names.

Comment: We are using SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12 SP2 and I use bash.

Comment: Ok, I don' have a OpenSUSE Enterprise box to test it, so I'll assume that your distribution's bash works like mine. Take a look at my comment on Jeff's answer and if it doesn't solve your doubts I'll elaborate better in a proper answer, when having access to a desktop computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$(ls split*`) command didn't *create* any filenames -- luckily! It also didn't create an array. What it *did* do was call `ls` with the `split*` wildcard, then paste all of the resulting output together (removing newlines that `ls` added between each filename and at the very end) and assign that conglomerate to your variable. When you then called `echo $a`, an *extra* bit of processing happened that you don't want: the contents of your variable were further subjected to splitting on whitespace ($IFS) and wildcard expansions. You lucked out by not having any files named, for example, `split space file` or `split more*`!

The root of your confusion is that you do, indeed, have a file named `split-data-1:` in that directory, and `ls` is happily handing it back to you.

What you want to do, instead, is to find a wildcard that suits the files that you really want, and use a simple array assignment:

```
a=(split_sam*)
```

or

```
a=(split*)
```

as you originally wrote, which will still include that `split-data-1:` file.

You can then iterate over the files or operate on them as a whole:

```
for file in "${a[@]}"
do
  ls -d -- "$file"
done
```

or

```
ls -d -- "${a[@]}"
```

Comment: I tried `a=(split_sam*)` but I got only one file instead of 3. What did I miss?

Comment: @user977828 You got three files in the array `a`. You probably only looked at the first one with `echo $a`.  To see all entries in the array, look at `"${a[@]}"`.

Comment: You actually got only three files because one of your files is not called "split sam something" that is what the `split-sam*` expression is looking for. The last file is "split data something" and will only be matched by a `split-data*` or `split*` expression.

Comment: Do you have a *directory* at this level, named with a "split_sam*" pattern that contains the four files from your question?